# Why sign in with Facebook stopped working?

Tags: android, facebook, android-facebook

I am using sign in with Facebook in my Android app. I have a fragment with Facebook's Sign in button. Once user press the button I was getting login result with access token, but now I am getting the message like this:

```
{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[public_profile,user_friends, email]}
```

I already checked project's Dashboard and doesn't seem to me suspicious:
[image]

I just wondering what could happen last month that changed the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if you are using the latest version of Facebook SDK? If not, replace the current one with the latest and then try.

Comment: Yes, I use "compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0'" in my gradle file.